# Loosen or even eliminate vote-change lockdown window for Community Wiki posts

Tags: discussion, feature-request, community-wiki, meta

I understand the danger of tactical downvoting.  It's clearly gaming the system.  But what about Community Wiki posts (on Meta, at least)?  Nobody is there to gain rep; there is no reason anyone would possibly want to tactically downvote anything.

After witnessing active Meta activity in Area 51 sites, where the environment of the entire newly-formed website can change and shift *drastically* within the time span of even a few days, **very** important Community Wiki meta questions can see answers shift from extremely relevant and helpful to horribly irrelevant and even destructive to the progress of the developing community.

I'd perhaps like the ability to be able to change positions that I support over time, as the landscape of the issue changes drastically around me.  And I really don't see any downside, honestly.  If anyone has any, please point them out.

Comment: Do I really have to give this a bounty?

Comment: I initially wanted to downvote this, but on second thought, I would like to see some examples of where questions have become irrelevant and/or destructive before I choose how to vote.

Comment: Having seen no examples after almost a month, -1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just like to point out: If it is community wiki, you can edit it (changing nothing) and change your vote.

Comment: Man ... I sound just like Jeff...

Comment: needz moar youtube linksss...